# Write a directory structure (pseudo code)

Tags: writing, file-structure, directory-structure

I am writing a wiki article and wondering what is the proper way to write a directory scheme?

I am doing something like

```
main folder
- sub folder
- sub folder
...
```

But I'm stuck after that.

Any help?

Comment: Where are you stuck? This looks OK to me. What's the problem?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: I have folders under that? Do I just keep adding -'s?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
root
  - sub1
    - sub1a
    - sub1b
  - sub2
  - sub3
```

keep the indention consistent ( I used 2 spaces ) and use a `<pre/>` or `<code/>` block in your html

you can try and make it look more like a tree control with a `|` if you want to stick to ASCII characters

```
root
  |- sub1
  | |- sub1a
  | |- sub1b
  |- sub2
  |- sub3
```

or use Unicode Characters from the Character Map Software provided by your Operating System

```
root
  ├ sub1
  | ├ sub1a
  | └ sub1b
  ├ sub2
  └ sub3
```

Answer (score 4):

I find the output of the `tree` command very readable. Here's an example that uses Jarrod's directory structure:

```
root
├── sub1
│   ├── sub1a
│   └── sub1b
├── sub2
└── sub3
```